# Rule to move message from specific sender to a folder sends wrong incoming messages to folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I have a rule for Outlook to move messages from a specific sender to a specific folder. What I'm seeing instead is that all new messages from random senders are being sent to the specified folder. I attempted to run the rule on messages which were in my inbox previously, and in this case the rule worked as expected, so it seems to only be new messages that are being sent to the folder wrongly. Is there something I'm not understanding about the way rules are applied?

This is the only rule I have setup in Outlook. Here's the rule's description:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
from user@domain.com
move it to the Specified folder
 and stop processing more rules
```

Another note, as I'm unsure if this is relevant or not, but the sender address I specify is an automated sender.

EDIT: After Further Investigation: I've determined that if a user is 'flagged' by this rule to be sent to the specified folder, messages from that user will always be sent to that folder.

EDIT: I attempted to set a rule to intercept senders that were being sent incorrectly, by targeting their emails specifically and disallowing further rule execution, but this then prevented the email I actually wanted to be moved from being moved. It seems that somehow several emails are being identified as from the same sender though their address are different.

Comment: What type of email account is this? POP3, IMAP, Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to complicate the rule by requiring that not only should the sender be the specified email, but the subject should include certain text. This works for my current situation, but I can see scenarios where I might need exceptions to this rule, and the current misbehavior would prevent that. As such, I won't accept this answer as it doesn't solve the root problem.